# Where can I find name data for US census years other than 1990?

Tags: dataset, census

After a little searching, I was able to find data from the 1990 US census on the frequency of male and female first names, and on surnames. That data is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110103145240/http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/names_files.html). I'm not able to find similar data for any other census years, however. Does anyone know where I can get data for other years, both earlier and later?

Comment: This question is off topic according to [a meta discussion](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/486/919).  However, many of the answers are on topic and useful.  Therefore I suggest we leave this thread open and I'm leaving the present comment in case the issue comes up with future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this post](http://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/38183-Baby-Names), my friend John May links to http://www.ssa.gov/OACT/babynames/; I believe it only has the top 1000 most popular first names for both sexes, but for all years since 1879. (John's post [and the followup](http://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/38177-Baby-Names--Continued) are interesting in their own right - he looks at popular unisex baby names.)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of information I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A search for a name on [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Eric) gives some stats and a distribution graph of ages.

At the bottom of the output is a 'Source information' link, which results in a popup with a bunch of references.  One is the ssa.gov babynames (link above).  Most of the references are for other countries (mostly English speaking), but the **[AGNAMES](https://web.archive.org/web/20110921022119/http://users.erols.com/dgalbi/names/agnames.htm) link  looks really good**, with "Popular Given Names US, 1801-1999" data and some normalization code.

At the bottom of the Wolfram|Alpha sources popup is this statement:

> "Requests by researchers for detailed
> information on the sources for
> individual Wolfram|Alpha results can
> be directed here."

where the popup has the actual link.  Seeing that Wolfram|Alpha output is all images of text and not text, I am not sure how open they are to sharing, but you could inquire.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the census bureau using a help line number from census.gov. It usually takes a few tries and patience with bureaucracy, but they've always been helpful to me.

The census doesn't release individual names in their data sets, so it will have to be a census bureau created aggregation.